# how to calculate download speed from total bandwidth?

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection, bandwidth

- If my internet Bandwidth is 100 Mbps , what should be the download speed ?
- how is calculated ?
- is there any way to monitor the most host starving the bandwidth ?

Comment: That's like saying, "I have a 4" diameter pipe.  How fast does water come out?"

Comment: As there are 8 bits per byte 100 Mbps equals 12.5 MBytes/sec. Due to network overhead 10 MBs is more realistic. But that is only the theoretical maximum. On the Internet there are a large number of factors, most of them beyond your control, that will limit this to less, sometimes much less.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, it is 12.5MB/s maximum, since "bps" means "bits per second", and a byte ("B") is 8 bits.

However, this is a THEORETICAL speed. Actual speed depends on various things. In our country, if an ISP provides a bandwidth lower than 90% of its nominal speed, it should provide a full refund to the customer if asked.

You can monitor the bandwidth consuming on Task Manager, if you have a Windows version higher than 7 or 8.